# uppercase sensitive php mac

Tags: php, macos

I have my development website on a mac, and php don't care with uppercase and lowercase.
But when I set my website on production server (debian) I have problems because I forgot to set uppercase.

Is there a solution to set php on mac case sensitive ?

for exemple

```
$test = new test();
```

will work on dev but not on prod

Thanks

Comment: Are you autoloading? Otherwise wut?

Comment: Always assume your environment is case-sensitive. Then stop writing sloppy code.

Comment: Yes I autoload with Symfony2

Comment: Use a map based autoloader instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a PHP behaviour, but you are likely to have an autoloader that loads the class definition when needed. Different from Windows and OS X' HFS*, Unix/Linux' filesystems are usually case sensitive. So while PHP doesn't care about the case of `new test()`, the autoloader can't find the right file on the case-sensitive Linux filesystem.

The only good solution really is to adjust the case so the autoloaded class name matches the file name.

<sub>* = HFS apparently has a switch that can make it case sensitive. But that won't help you in this situation.</sub>

Comment: Note: switching to Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive,Journaled) will cause some OS X applications to not work properly.